# Hard deleted items in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

recently I make a powershell script which compare date of create item in sharepoint and delete if it is equal or less.

But, my bad and I didnt check some data and they are gone.

Recycle bin in Collection administrator is empty, it is some way to recover this data back ?

I am working on SharePoint 2010 onpremis.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: If you don’t have any backups of the content database where the site collection exist there is no way to recover the content.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the recycle bin of the original site content beside the Site Collection? what command did you use to delete from powershell?